# Two menus one for desktop one for mobile, screen reader issues?

Tags: responsive-webdesign, accessibility

Suppose a webpage has two menus, one for a "desktop" sized screen and another for tablets/phones. It might looks something like this:

```
<body>
<div class="hide-me-on-wide-screens">
   <ul>
     ...menu items...
   </ul>
</div>
<header>
  <img class="logo">
  <div class="hide-me-on-narrow-screens">
    <ul>
       ...the same menu items again...
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Css hides and shows the appropriate menu using media queries and `display: none`

My question is, will this be a problem for people who use screen readers? If so how can we mitigate this, assuming that we don't want to refactor our HTML.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/ screen readers ignore content that is set to `display:none;`.    When you hide one or the other menu, modern screen readers should be able to interpret your site correctly.

For you site to be usable with a screen reader, it is a good idea to include a link at the very top of that skips to the main content and bypasses the menus.   Screen readers work much better when the users can bypass the navigation and quickly get to the content. The article I linked has code that can hide that link visually, but still make it available to screen readers.